# Python: Program running fine but skipping over output lines in code

Tags: python

When I run the following code:

```
def collatz(number):
   if number % 2 == 0:
       return number // 2
       result = number
       print(number)
   elif number % 2 == 1:
       return 3 * number + 1
       result = number
       print(number)


n = input('Enter a number: ')
while n != 1:
   n = collatz(int(n))
```

the code runs to get the number to 1, but it always seems to skip the lines

```
result = number
print(number)
```

because it does not show any output. But when I visualize it, it is running the number to one. Could someone help explain why that is happening? Thanks so much.

Comment: May you explain the goal of your code a bit more clearly?

Comment: Because when the function gets to return it exits.  Put print and variable assignment before return statement.

Answer (score 0):

this is because it returns the value and it doesn't continue after the return, so you could do:

```
def collatz(number):
   if number % 2 == 0:
       result = number / 2
       print(result)
       return result
   elif number % 2 == 1:
       result = 3 * number + 1
       print(result)
       return result


n = input('Enter a number: ')
while n != 1:
   n = collatz(int(n))
```

Comment: The number still needs to be returned - this will make the code fail.

Comment: okok i'll fix it.

Answer (score 0):

When a function sees `return` it ends immediately and outputs the value after the word. So to get the lines to run, they need to be before the word `return`:

```py
def collatz(number):
   if number % 2 == 0:
       result = number
       print(number)
       return number // 2
   elif number % 2 == 1:
       result = number
       print(number)
       return 3 * number + 1


n = input('Enter a number: ')
while n != 1:
   n = collatz(int(n))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a recursive loop that bypasses those two statements.

```
def collatz(number):
   if number % 2 == 0:
       return number // 2 <---- exits function here
       result = number
       print(number)
   elif number % 2 == 1:
       return 3 * number + 1  <---- exits function here
       result = number
       print(number)
```

The same concept applies if you have the following function.

```
def add(x,y):
    return x + y
    print(x)
```

You would never get to the print(x) statement as you are exiting the function before that line of code!

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `return` statement. Return exits the `collatz` function immediatly.